# Nested mutations don't seem to work in Lighthouse 3.7

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I'm trying to setup a schema in Lighthouse 3.7/Laravel 5.8
What I want to achieve is this:
A User should be able to create Clists.
There is a One to Many relation between User and Clist.
And I'm trying to implement nested mutations as described [here](https://lighthouse-php.com/3.7/eloquent/nested-mutations.html#belongs-to).

I have already implemented the "query" part and it works fine.
But when I test a createClist mutation in GraphQL Playground, I get this error:

```
"debugMessage": "Array to string conversion",

"message": "Internal server error",

"extensions": {
        "category": "internal"
      },
...
```

And I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
type Mutation {
  createClist(input: CreateClistInput! @spread): Clist @create
}

input CreateClistInput {
    name: String!
    description: String
    starred: Boolean
    user: CreateUserRelation!
    ctags: CreateCtagRelation
}

input CreateUserRelation {
  connect: ID!
}

input CreateCtagRelation {
  create: [CreateCtagInput!]
  connect: [ID!]
  sync: [ID!]
}

input CreateCtagInput {
  name: String!
}
```

And here is a screenshot of GraphQL Playground:

[image]

Comment: Can you show your model? When using Lighthouse `@spread` directive it is required to typehint the return type of the relationships.  https://lighthouse-php.com/3.7/eloquent/nested-mutations.html#return-types-required

Comment: This is it! It works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I posted it as a answer so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using the `@spread` directive a typehint on the relationship in your model is required.

Taken from the [docs](https://lighthouse-php.com/3.7/eloquent/nested-mutations.html#return-types-required) there is the following example:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;

class Post extends Model 
{
    // WORKS
    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    // DOES NOT WORK
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);        
    }
}
```

Lighthouse uses the type hint to determine how it should handle the relationship.